# Declare right type to fit in function calling with generic type

Tags: java, class, generics

I'm new in JAVA, and I got some problem in manage my data which will regist them by using other people's function.

So I have a ToServerMessagePack here, which store two class in it.

```
public class ToServerMessagePack<T extends IMessage>{
    Class<T> iMessageClass;
    Class<? extends IMessageHandler<T, IMessage>> handlerClass;

    public ToServerMessagePack(Class<T> iMessageClassIn, Class<? extends IMessageHandler<T, IMessage>> handlerClassIn){
        this.iMessageClass = iMessageClassIn;
        this.handlerClass = handlerClassIn;

        Messages.sendToServerList.add(this);
    }

    public Class<T> getIMessageClass(){
        return iMessageClass;
    }

    public Class<? extends IMessageHandler<T, IMessage>> getHandlerClass(){
        return handlerClass;
    }
}
```

ToServerMessagePack will add itself to a list in Messages class when construct.

Then I declare some ToServerMessagePack in Messages class here.

```
public class Messages{
    public static List<ToServerMessagePack<? extends IMessage>> sendToServerList = new ArrayList<ToServerMessagePack<? extends IMessage>>();

    public static ToServerMessagePack<MarketMessage> MARKET = new ToServerMessagePack<MarketMessage>(MarketMessage.class, MarketMessage.Handler.class);
    public static ToServerMessagePack<RecipeTableMessage> RECIPE_TABLE = new ToServerMessagePack<RecipeTableMessage>(RecipeTableMessage.class, RecipeTableMessage.Handler.class);

    public static void regist(){
        for(int i = 0; i <= sendToServerList.size()-1; i ++){
            ToServerMessagePack<? extends IMessage> element = sendToServerList.get(i);
            FoodPower.network.registerMessage(element.getIMessageClass(), element.getHandlerClass(), i, Side.SERVER);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem happended on my main purpose that I regist it using a function called registerMessage which declare like this.

```
public <REQ extends IMessage, REPLY extends IMessage> void registerMessage(Class<? extends IMessageHandler<REQ, REPLY>> messageHandler, Class<REQ> requestMessageType, int discriminator, Side side)
```

The IDE complaint that the arguments is not applicable like these.

```
The method registerMessage(Class<? extends IMessageHandler<REQ,REPLY>>, Class<REQ>, int, Side) in the type SimpleNetworkWrapper is not applicable for the arguments (Class<capture#2-of ? extends IMessage>, Class<capture#4-of ? extends IMessageHandler<capture#3-of ? extends IMessage,IMessage>>, int, Side)
```

I found that it said "capture#2-of ? extends IMessage" and "capture#3-of ? extends IMessage", which may be the main problem because they sould be the same class like "REQ" said in function registerMessage declaration.

Is there anyway to let IDE know they are same class by declare right type to "element" or any other way to fix this?

---

UPDATE

What I did before is something like this, and it worked perfectly.

```
FoodPower.network.registerMessage(MarketMessage.Handler.class, MarketMessage.class, 0, Side.SERVER);
FoodPower.network.registerMessage(RecipeTableMessage.Handler.class, RecipeTableMessage.class, 1, Side.SERVER);
```

MarketMessage is a class implement IMessage like this

```
public class MarketMessage implements IMessage
```

Handler is a "inner class" in MarketMessage implement IMessageHandler like this

```
public static class Handler extends MessageHandlerBase implements IMessageHandler<MarketMessage, IMessage>
```

So does RecipeTableMessage.

I just trying using a new way to manage my message classes(because I may add a lot new message classes in future), and avoid hardcode on parameter "int discriminator" in registerMessage.

---

UPDATE

I found a way to solve my problem, but still open for new answer or suggestion.

I add a method in ToServerMessagePack, called registThis.

```
public void registThis(int discriminator){
    FoodPower.network.registerMessage(this.handlerClass, this.iMessageClass, discriminator, Side.SERVER);
}
```

And call registThis in regist method in Messages. That is, I let registion process in ToServerMessagePack class instead in Messages class.

```
public static void regist(){
    for(int i = 0; i <= sendToServerList.size()-1; i ++){
        sendToServerList.get(i).registThis(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using Class in the parameters to registerMessage.

Comment: @NomadMaker What do you mean? BTW, I also edit with some new information.

Comment: The line that reads:     public ToServerMessagePack(Class<T> iMessageClassIn, Class<? extends IMessageHandler<T, IMessage>> handlerClassIn) should probably read    public ToServerMessagePack(T iMessageClassIn, T handlerClassIn).

Comment: @NomadMaker  OOPS, sorry I make you confused. Handler is a inner class 
implement IMessageHandler in MarketMessage. I also updated the question.

Comment: I truly think that you are using generics when normal inheritance will do the job more clearly.

Comment: @NomadMaker Ok......seems that I need to learn hard about how to use generics in a clearly way. It's hard for me xd. BTW, I found a way to solve this problem. But still open for new answer or suggestion.

Comment: I think that generics are great for collections. They are useful when you would otherwise have to pass and return Object's.